# SoapUI insert xml from file in soap request

Tags: soapui

Does anyboday know if it is possible to insert xml from local file in a soap request? and how to?

What I input in the editor window

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <sendXml>
         <arg0>file:MyXml.xml</arg2>
      </sendXml>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

What I expect in the actuall soap message:-

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <sendXml>
         <arg0>&lt;MyXml&gt;Info&lt;/MyXml&gt;</arg2>
      </sendXml>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the context.

Put a symbol that looks like this you XML:

```
${myFileStuff}
```

In a Groovy Step that is executed before this put:

```
    BufferedReader br = null;

    try {

        String sCurrentLine = "";
        String myFileStuff= "";

        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\testing.txt"));

        while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            myFileStuff += sCurrentLine;
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (br != null)br.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    context.setProperty("myFileStuff", myFileStuff)
```

I slightly modified the code example here for the file read.  There are many ways to go:

http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-file-from-java-bufferedreader-example/

You can get the import statements there.

Comment: the code of Groovy Step can be simplified to a single line: context.setProperty("myFileStuff", new File('C:\\testing.txt').text)