# Insert partial SOAP request from lines of a file in SoapUI

Tags: xml, soap, soapui

I'm working on testing a SOAP service. I have generated lots of request bodies in files (several requests per file, one request per line). I would like to be able to feed these bodies into SoapUI. I saw [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10878032/soapui-insert-xml-from-file-in-soap-request#), but that's working on the assumption of one chunk of XML per file.

Comment: What is your use case? You can even create a file for each request.

Comment: I'm doing regression testing on a SOAP service. With ~1/3 coverage, I'm at around 770k cases (this is a very complicated service), so 700k+ files would not be practical.